# Want to delete column that has lowest quantity of data after breaking up a categorical value

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi i am creating a matrix function that would be n-1. But i want to delete the categorical variable that has least amount in n columns. How to do that.

```
   BreakCad= function(dataf,catog)  # takes the parent data frame and the variable containing categorical variable.

{

  result<- model.matrix(~ factor(catog)-1) ##--Takes input a categorical variable breaks to n-1 categorical variable with value  0 or 1--#

result<-result[,-1] # its removing col in position -1 , I want to remove the #knonw which has lowest quantity

result= as.data.frame(result)

 result=cbind(dataf,result)

  return(result)

}

y= data.frame(Decision=sample(c("yes","no","cant decide"),40,replace=TRUE ),point1=sample(1:10, 40, replace=TRUE))

fd=BreakCad(y,y$Decision)

min(table(y$Decision))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `relevel` function to put selected level of `catog` first. A toy example:

```
(catog<-factor(rep(letters[1:4], 4:1)))
[1] a a a a b b b c c d
Levels: a b c d
```

Find level with lowest count:

```
(wmin<-which.min(table(catog)))
d 
4
```

Set it as first level:

```
(catog<-relevel(catog, wmin))
[1] a a a a b b b c c d
Levels: d a b c
```

Then your code should work.

```
result<-model.matrix(~factor(catog)-1)
result<-result[,-1]
```